# External script fails to load all drivers

Tags: database, external-scripts

Attempting to create an external script that allows me to query some things in Drupal. I was hoping to be able to use my external databases I have defined in the settings of my site to query some of their tables. As one of the databses is Oracle based I have the http://drupal.org/project/oracle module installed.

The following is a PHP script outside of PHP but on the same server (different host):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.example.com';

define('DRUPAL_ROOT','/usr/share/drupal7/');

//require the bootstrap include
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'./includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 
$db1 = Database::getConnection('oracle','external');
$sql = "SELECT * from accounts";
$result = $db1->query($sql);
$accounts = $result->fetchObject();
print_r($accounts);
```

This code errors with:

```
PDOException: could not find driver in main()
```

The same code (just the Database::getConnection down) running from within a Drupal page works fine. What can I do to make this code execute externally?

Comment: It seams Oracle module dose not loaded, try http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_all/7

Comment: DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL should force drupal to load all modules see, so look into oracle module, maybe you should include some files manually form Oracle module

Comment: The drivers are files to copy in includes/database/oracle. The module not being loaded doesn't change anything.